# Pyathena SQL Query with Python condition

Tags: python, sql, pyathena

The following python list is given:

```
customer_list = [123,567,494]
```

Now I want to run a SQL query in which I use the list from above. How can I add the condition *in (customer_list)* to my query?

I tried:

```
my_query = """
select * from my_table
where customer in ("""+customer_list")" 
"""
order by name
"""
```

which gives me the error:
*TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like :

```
customer_list = [123,567,494]

my_query = """
select * from my_table
where customer in ({cust_list}) 
order by name
""".format(cust_list=",".join(str(x) for x in customer_list))
```

**Output:**

```
select * from my_table where customer in (123,567,494) order by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can relpace customer_list in your query with :

```
', '.join(str(element) for element in customer_list)
```